# Android AES Decrypt

Tags: android

I'm a PHP programmer trying to code Android App. I've done a good job until now ... Now i'm stuck ...

I'm calling this class below to decrypt a previously encrypted string in php ..
The string is sent and received ok by the class but for unknown reasons the decrypt function always returns null.

Example:

unencrypted text: test

encryption key: SeoavcVARXhWKdQ5

encryption iv: TeoavcVARXhWKdQ5

encrypted text: NnUDIfVXvtamcrYWvs9HWw==

When calling decrypt(key, iv, text) i get null ...

Any help please ?!

```
import android.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESCipher {

    private static String CIPHER_NAME = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    private static int CIPHER_KEY_LEN = 16; //128 bits

    public static String decrypt(String key, String initVector, String data) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(AESCipher.CIPHER_NAME);
            SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT), "AES");
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k, iv);


            byte[] decodedEncryptedData = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] original = c.doFinal(decodedEncryptedData);
            return new String(original);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

LE:
PHP CODE to encrypt

```
class AESCipher {
    private static $OPENSSL_CIPHER_NAME = "aes-128-cbc";
    private static $CIPHER_KEY_LEN = 16;
    static function encrypt2($key, $iv, $data) {
        if (strlen($key) < AESCipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            $key = str_pad("$key", AESCipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN, "0");
        } else if (strlen($key) > AESCipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            $key = substr($str, 0, AESCipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN);
        }
        $encodedEncryptedData = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, AESCipher::$OPENSSL_CIPHER_NAME, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
        return $encodedEncryptedData;

    }
}
```

Comment: [refer this ans i hope it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372658/2794507)

Comment: Post the PHP code...

Comment: The php code works. I've encoded/decoded in php , everything is ok. It's the Android code that's the issue

Comment: @HardikVasani that uses another encryption ... i'm trying to figure this one ... anyway ... i'm also encrypting some stuff on android and sending to php ... and that works ... the problem is when i'm encrypting in php and sending to android, the android doesn't decrypt .. ( and the php side is ok )

Comment: The PHP code would still help so we can see how you're encrypting it. For example, your key and your iv look similar, but one call getBytes() on the iv, and base64 decode the key, which is suspicious.

Comment: I'm asking you to post the PHP code so we can see how you've encrypted the original data...

Comment: I already got my answer and the encode/decode now works great but for future reference i posted the PHP code I use for encrypting in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is not base64 encoded (it is 16 characters long for a 16 bytes key). Use `getBytes` instead :

```
SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
```

This yields the decoded text "test".

Comment: That was a good remark and changed the code but I'm still getting null returns :(

Comment: that is strange, with the exact same code I get the result "test". What are the error and stacktrace ? (you should find it in the logcat)

Comment: Thank you so much bwt !!! The last part was my fault. I url encoded the string when I sent it from php and forgot to decode it before decrypting it in Android. It works !!! Thanks again !